# First slide count doesn't work on clicking next for Bootstrap 4 Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the slide/total count and got it working somehow. However, when I click `next` and it goes back to the original first slide, it doesn't show `1/4` but it remains `4/4`.

**JSFiddel: https://jsfiddle.net/zorw7yLe/**

HTML:

```
<div class="num"></div>
<a class="next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next"> -->>></a>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="First slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h5>Title of the first image</h5>
        <p>Some description of the first image</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="Second slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h5>Title of the second image</h5>
        <p>Some description for the second image</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="Third slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h5>Title of the third image</h5>
        <p>Some description for the third image</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="Fourth slide">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h5>Title of the fourth image</h5>
        <p>Some description for the fourth image</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;
var currentIndex = $('.carousel-item.active').index() + 1;
var down_index;
$('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');

    $(".next").click(function(){
    currentIndex_active = $('.carousel-item.active').index() + 2;
    if (totalItems >= currentIndex_active)
    {
        down_index= $('.carousel-item.active').index() + 2;
        $('.num').html(''+currentIndex_active+'/'+totalItems+'');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use bootstrap carousel events, you don't need to watch the click directly on your link :

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events

```
var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length; 

$('#carouselExampleIndicators').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    $('.num').html((e.to+1)+'/'+totalItems);
});
```

So your counter will keep track of the current slide

Also, your counter doesn't come back to 1/4 because of your condition (totalItems >= currentIndex_active), at the last slide if you add +2 on your index, that's 5, which is higher than totalItems (4)

You'll need a else to eventualy get the right number, but just use the bootstrap events

Comment: Oh sweet. That works like a charm except that it doesn't show up on loading until I click. How do I go about that?

Comment: You may want to wait for the document to be loaded maybe, on this fiddle it's working
https://jsfiddle.net/vt57bq0c/1/

Comment: Also, you don't need the extra empty string at the end of your values, see an exemple here : https://jsfiddle.net/Lekdynoa/